# Customizing StyleCop

Tags: stylecop

Our company is planning on implementing StyleCop (gulp!) and I'm interested in what level of customization occurs in different companies/environments.  I've "heard" that most people just accept the default rules without too many exclusions, but want to get some more feedback.

Thanks

Jim Stanley
Blackboard Connect

Comment: It's not very customizable.  We disabled a few rules, and there are ways of manually excluding others on a per-case scenario (similarly to how you can suppress code analysis warnings, but you have to code up the suppressions by hand...)  Also, it will be painful at first, especially if you/other coders are sloppy about whitespace, braces, etc.  But I thought it was worth it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm a heavy customizer.  I examine each and every rule prior to deciding whether or not to include it in a "baseline" rule set.  I also add many custom rules.

I too have seen cases where organizations adopt the default active rule set as their baseline, and it makes me cringe every time.  Some of the default rules are really quite terrible when one starts to consider aspects like accessibility and minimizing diff/blame noise, and they really do merit substitution with something a little better planned...